# Красивые ссылки

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте! Мне нужна помощь! Не могу решить проблему с .htaccess

Дело в том, что мне нужно преобразовать ссылку cabinets.php?id=12&page=index в cabinets/12/index

Вставила в .htaccess следующий код:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^cabinets/(.*)$ cabinets.php?id=$1 [L]
```

А он не помогает. 
То есть открываю ссылку cabinets/12/ выводит что по ай ди. Открываю cabinets/12/index ничего....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день!
Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^cabinets/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z]+)$ cabinets.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Comment: @Ксения Астахова: немного опоздал)

Answer (score 1):

У Вас значение для параметра `page` никак не учитывается. Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^cabinets/(\d+)/?(.*)$ cabinets.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L]

## id - всегда числовое значение
## page - необязательный параметр
```

Comment: Всем большое спасибо!) Вы мне очень помогли)